# Put the text below image in Android ListView

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

I want to put the text below image like picture below:

[image]

the layout coding now :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dip" >

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
<--some coding here -->
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip">

            <ImageView     
                android:id="@+id/list_image"   
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/test"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

anyone know how to make it like the photo because rite now, the text in the center of the image.

thank you,.

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` instead of this  `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: Better to use `android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"` in my opinion cause with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` the text will be over the image on its bottom, not below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` by `android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"` + `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dip" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

<--some coding here -->
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip">

```
        <ImageView     
            android:id="@+id/list_image"   
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/test"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this stuff really helps you..

Instead of an ImageView and Textview ,have an option to set image and text inside

> ```
>            <Button 
>             android:id="@+id/textwithImage"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:drawableTop="@drawable/test"
>             android:text="test"
>             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
>             android:typeface="sans"
>             android:textSize="15dip"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:padding="15dp"                
>             />
> ```